# Creating n-hot vector in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have

```
q = np.array(['a', 'b']) 
terms = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

How can I create a n-hot vector v, as `[1, 1, 0, 0]`, such that every item that appears in q will have its' index set to 1 in a zero-vector of `length = len(terms)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html), and turn it into an array of `int`:

```
>>> np.isin(terms,q).astype(int)
array([1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have pandas, you can use the `pd.Index` API for very fast (constant time) searching per term:

```
>>> idx = pd.Index(q)
>>> (idx.get_indexer_for(terms) >= 0).astype(int)
array([1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Another option is broadcasted comparison:

```
>>> (q == terms[:, None]).any(1).astype(int)
array([1, 1, 0, 0])
```

This is fast, but you should prefer the first option, or @sacul's answer for large (~1M) data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `searchsorted` based method that is fast and readily applicable to batches of vectors:

Timings for 4, 12 and 26 classes and batches of 1000 vectors of length 2. `broadcast` is @coldspeed's method.

```
4
broadcast   :      0.248 ms
searchsorted:      0.095 ms
12
broadcast   :      0.468 ms
searchsorted:      0.119 ms
26
broadcast   :      0.748 ms
searchsorted:      0.137 ms
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase

def broadcast(test, classes):
    return (test[..., None] == classes).any(-2).view(np.uint8)

def searchsorted(test, classes):
    X = classes.argsort()
    out = np.zeros((*test.shape[:-1], classes.size), np.uint8)
    idx = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, out.shape))]
    idx = *idx[:-1], X[classes[X].searchsorted(test)]
    out[idx] = 1
    return out

letters = np.fromiter(ascii_lowercase, 'U1', 26)
np.random.shuffle(letters)

def make_test(n=26, shp=(1000,)):
    v = np.random.randint(0, n, shp)
    w = (np.random.randint(0, n-1, shp) + 1 + v) % n
    d = len(shp)
    return letters[:n], letters[np.r_[f'{d},{d+1},0', v, w]]

from timeit import timeit

def test_it(f, args, n=1000, format='{0.__name__:12s}: {1:10.3f} ms'.format):
    res = timeit('f(*args)', globals=dict(f=f, args=args), number=n) * 1000/n
    return res, format(f, res)

for k in [4, 12, 26]:
    T, L = make_test(k)
    print(k)
    for f in [broadcast, searchsorted]:
        t, msg = test_it(f, (L, T))
        print(msg)
```